# Getting java to display more than 1 .add()

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, layout-manager

I've started learning basic Java and wanted to rewrite a Game Map Generator that I've once wrote in PHP. I've got part of it working fine (This is just the start), but whenever I want to display 2 things (using .add()), it will only display one of them. Heres my code;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame m1 = new JFrame();
    Container con = m1.getContentPane();
    Color c = new Color(16, 174, 0);
    con.setBackground(c);
    m1.setSize(mapWidth, mapHeight);
    m1.setTitle("ThomasMosey's Map Generator"); // Window Title
    m1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    m1.add(new User());
    m1.add(new Grid());
    m1.setVisible(true);
}
```

It's only part of the code, but I was wondering if it's anything I've done wrong with .add there.

Thank you in advance.

---

This is the full code;

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Map extends JFrame {
    public static int mapWidth = 576; // The Map's Width
    public static int mapHeight = 598; // The Map's Height
    public static int userX = 1;
    public static int userY = 1;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame m1 = new JFrame();
        Container con = m1.getContentPane();
        Color c = new Color(16, 174, 0);
        con.setBackground(c);
        m1.setSize(mapWidth, mapHeight);
        m1.setTitle("ThomasMosey's Map Generator"); // Window Title
        m1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        con.add(new User(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        con.add(new Grid(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        m1.setVisible(true);
    }
}
// The Grid system
class Grid extends JComponent {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        Color gridColor = new Color(0, 84, 12);
        g2.setColor(gridColor);
        int i;
        int i2;
        for(i = 50; i <= Map.mapWidth; i += 51) {
            g2.drawLine(0, i, Map.mapWidth, i);
        }
        for(i2 = 50; i2 <= Map.mapHeight; i2 += 51) {
            g2.drawLine(i2, 0, i2, Map.mapHeight);
        }
    }
}
// Drawing the Grid but lower down to give a significant difference to check whether or not it's actually drawing on the JFrame
class User extends JComponent {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public void paint(Graphics g2) {
        Graphics2D g22 = (Graphics2D) g2;
        g22.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        Color gridColor = new Color(0, 84, 12);
        g22.setColor(gridColor);
        int i22;
        for(i22 = 50; i22 <= 6000; i22 += 53) {
            g22.drawLine(0, i22, Map.mapWidth, i22+1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"It's only part of the code.."*  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).  If you had, I'd have **tested** my answer before posting it.

Comment: I've just posted my full code. It's not a very large file.

Comment: That is a classic SSCCE.  See my edit for further tips.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The default layout for a content pane is `BorderLayout`.
2. Add a component to a border layout with no constraint and it ends up in the `CENTER`.
3. Only one component can appear in each part of a border layout.

---

So try this instead..

```
m1.add(new User(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
m1.add(new Grid(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

---

Part of the problem is that custom components have a default preferred size of 0x0.  Try this variant.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Map extends JFrame {
    public static int mapWidth = 576; // The Map's Width
    public static int mapHeight = 598; // The Map's Height
    public static int userX = 1;
    public static int userY = 1;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame m1 = new JFrame();
        Container con = m1.getContentPane();
        Color c = new Color(16, 174, 0);
        con.setBackground(c);
        // bad form - pack() instead
        //m1.setSize(mapWidth, mapHeight);
        m1.setTitle("ThomasMosey's Map Generator"); // Window Title
        m1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        User user = new User();
        user.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,300));
        con.add(user, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        Grid grid = new Grid();
        grid.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,600));
        con.add(grid, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        m1.pack();
        m1.setVisible(true);
    }
}
// The Grid system
class Grid extends JComponent {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        Color gridColor = new Color(0, 84, 12);
        g2.setColor(gridColor);
        int i;
        int i2;
        for(i = 50; i <= Map.mapWidth; i += 51) {
            g2.drawLine(0, i, Map.mapWidth, i);
        }
        for(i2 = 50; i2 <= Map.mapHeight; i2 += 51) {
            g2.drawLine(i2, 0, i2, Map.mapHeight);
        }
    }
}
// Drawing the Grid but lower down to give a significant difference to check whether or not it's actually drawing on the JFrame
class User extends JComponent {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g2) {
        Graphics2D g22 = (Graphics2D) g2;
        g22.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        Color gridColor = new Color(0, 84, 12);
        g22.setColor(gridColor);
        int i22;
        for(i22 = 50; i22 <= 6000; i22 += 53) {
            g22.drawLine(0, i22, Map.mapWidth, i22+1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding BorderLayout.CENTER and BorderLayout.PAGE_START doesn't change it. EDIT: Your second fix didn't work.

Comment: It worked, but I wanted them on top of each other. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What, the `Grid` and `User`?  Here the user **does** appear 'on top of' the `Grid`.  Did you mean that they should be layered?  That the user is transparent and you can see the grid **behind** it?

Comment: Yes - that is what I want, if possible. Sorry for not giving enough detail.

Comment: You might try using a `JLayeredPane`.  I won't post an example of that yet for 2 reasons. 1) I think it is the wrong approach, and that a single custom component should draw both the user and grid. 2) Using the `JLayeredPane` is a PITA, I have trouble wrapping my head around it. :)

Comment: Haha, thanks for your help! I will look in to making it all one class. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

The current layout of `JFrame` is `BorderLayout` and you are adding both these components at center. Try to change the layout.

```
Container con = m1.getContentPane();
con.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
```

or

```
m1.add(new User(),BorderLayout.NORTH);
m1.add(new Grid(),BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

EDIT: You have to override the setPreferredSize() method for User.

```
class User extends JComponent {
  public java.awt.Dimension getPreferredSize() { 
    return new java.awt.Dimension(100,100);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for re-instating your answer.  I was prepared to up-vote even before the advice on the preferred size.  (Though I disagree that it is best to override the method, but that is more a design question.)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIR,  content pane  baqcking JFrame accepts only single child by default. You will have to
set and configure some layout to have more than one child

Comment: -1 The content pane of a `JFrame` can accept **5** components without changing the layout.